# Custom Inheritance Representation in JAXB

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb

I have the following XML structure to read using JAXB:

```
<root>
    <record>
        <animal>Dog</animal>
        <trait>Swim</trait>
        <subrecord>
            <name>Charlie</name>
            <likes>Beef</likes>
        </subrecord>
        <subrecord>
            <name>Rocky</name>
            <likes>Pork</likes>
        </subrecord>
    </record>
    <record>
        <animal>Cat</animal>
        <likes>Fish</likes>
        <subrecord>
            <name>Bella</name>
            <trait>Bite</trait>
        </subrecord>
        <subrecord>
            <name>Molly</name>
            <trait>Claw</trait>
        </subrecord>
    </record>
</root>
```

Tags `<trait>` and `<likes>` can be either in `<record>` or in `<subrecord>`. If defined in both `<record>` and `<subrecord>`, then value in `<subrecord>` should shadow value in `<record>`.

subrecord should extend record and allow me to call methods below. I.e. for "Charlie" I should get:

```
subrecord.getAnimal() -> Dog
subrecord.getName() -> Charlie
subrecord.getTrait() -> Swim
subrecord.getLikes() -> Beef
```

Please help me to code classes for JAXB mapping.

Comment: Well, where do you have a problem? *What have you tried?*

Answer (score 0):

So you want to call methods in subrecord objects to get the record values. This is not a good idea.

The easiest way to use JAXB is to define your XSD first(If you don't want to define XSD by hand, use a tool that generate XSD from XML.) and use xjc to generate classes from XSD. Anything that deviates from this standard practice have to be done manually and you don't want to mix machine generated code with your written code.

You should create a helper method or wrapper class that can figure out the subrecord's values but I personally think the XML Schema should be defined correctly in the first place.